# why Openstack swift Object start giving me the below error?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04, virtual, openstack-swift

Hi I am trying to start openstack swift container, object, account but everytime I am getting the same error for those three cases.

root@nijhum-17101142:/etc/swift# swift-init object start

Starting object-server..(/etc/swift/object-server.conf) liberasurecode[4280]: liberasurecode_backend_open: dynamic linking error libJerasure.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory liberasurecode[4280]:
liberasurecode_backend_open: dynamic linking error libJerasure.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory liberasurecode[4280]: liberasurecode_backend_open: dynamic linking error libisal.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory liberasurecode[4280]: liberasurecode_backend_open: dynamic linking error libshss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory **Error trying to load config from /etc/swift/object-server.conf: (dnspython 1.12.0 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('dnspython>=1.15.0'), set(['swift']))**

Answer (score 0):

what is your object store backed ?  the  most  simplest is to create  a "storage node" from 2  block device with XFS  , but you can use ceph  storage for backed as well